# Reopened: "...word for those random spots/patterns you see when you enter your home after playing outside on a sunny day?"

Tags: support

I had posted this question today:

[Is there a word for those random spots/patterns you see when you enter your home after playing outside on a sunny day?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/312779)

It was marked as duplicate by Mari Lou A and it pointed to this question -> [The dark dot in your eye](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130724/the-dark-dot-in-your-eye)

It is not a duplicate because my question deals with a very specific scenario. While the answers to the previously posted question and those that I have received are same, my question is different in the sense that it is more restricted to light and temperature changes (transitioning from hot and sunny outdoors to relatively cool/dimly lit indoors). This specificity may probably lead to more specific answers.

The other question, is more generic in my view.

---

- **A problem can have many solutions. Likewise, can't many problems have the same solution? What is the ELU's consensus regarding this scenario?**
- **Can my question be reopened?**

---

### Update

My question has been reopened! I thanks this community for trusting me and to the users who voted in favor of reopening.

Comment: Many problems certainly can have the same solution, just as many questions actually have the same answer. The Stack Exchange duplicate status exists for just such a scenario.

Comment: You can vote to re-opon your own post which will make the count two now. You can explain why your question is not duplicate in the original question. It will help users vote to re-open it a great deal which will be placed in a review queue soon.

Comment: Your question is re-opened. So fast and effective...

Comment: Your question is re-re-opened.

Comment: You've been all very busy while I was out. Oh well, I'm glad to see things have settled out in the end. Perhaps only a medic or an ophthalmologist can really answer your question, it's no longer an English language question.

Answer (score 3):

The two questions are obviously related in both having to do with anomalies with the eye.

But the kinds of anomaly are described differently and therefore deserve two separate questions and their separate set of answers.

Frankly it would probably be best to ask of a medical practitioner, someone who has a technical vocabulary for these phenomena.

There is also a policy difficulty here. Five people originally voted to close as a duplicate. Then five more voted to reopen after this meta-question. Just now, a single user, with a phrase-request gold badge, hammer-voted to close as a duplicate. The process now, if people so desire still to reopen, is to canvass for further reopen votes.

Comment: Hi, Mitch. Five people didn't vote to close it. It was a single hammer in the first place.

Comment: @Rathony Oh. well, that's why they give them the hammer votes. But we can rise up to oppose the autocrats!

Comment: @Mitch - The [timeline](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/312779/timeline) of my question proves that a diamond mod had (re)reopened it after second time closure. The "hammer votes" are applicable to reopening as well, aren't they?